# SonarQube 4.4 won't start on Windows XP 32 bit

Tags: windows, tomcat, sonarqube

I did unzip SonarQube and tried using it by starting StartSonar.bat on Windows XP 32. I get this error which I am unable to solve.

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
jvm 1    | org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:335)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:72)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.StartServer.start(StartServer.java:37)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:49)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
jvm 1    | Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
jvm 1    |      ... 11 more
jvm 1    | Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9000]]
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:566)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
jvm 1    |      ... 13 more
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The same download works fine with Mac OS. Same windows XP runs Sonar version 3.7..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Don't know but somehow I change port from 9000 to 9009 and it started working

Comment: Do you by chance already have something running on port 9000? Like another instance of Sonar(Qube) :)?

Comment: When I said I changed the port from 9000 to 9009 .. It worked .. I had the very first question in my mind what you have asked. So obviously I tried that.. I had old Sonar working on 9000 port which I stopped and tested that noting is working on 9000. I tried running sonarqube 4.4 after that only but it dint work..